# Windows Forms/WPF app with standalone web server

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, webserver, webbrowser-control

I'm developing an application that runs e-learning courses on a USB stick or other detachable media on desktops without network/internet connection. The application needs to be a Windows (Forms or WPF) application.

The e-learning courses are all html/javascript based (supplied by a third party). My application therefore has to contain its own standalone web server to host the e-learning courses, and use a webbrowser control to render the courses. I will use the standard webbrowser control that comes with Windows Forms/WPF.

The standalone webserver has to be completely integrated in the application (i.e. no software installation by the user). Another requirement is that I can capture posts from the webbrowser to the webserver, in order to process & save course results to the USB stick.

I have looked at integrating Cassini, but if I understand correctly, Cassini only takes a local path to serve files from, and there is no possibility to intercept and handle requests yourself. Another possibility is to use a `HttpListener` and basically write a simple webserver from scratch (probably with very poor efficiency).

Does anybody have any suggestions? I can still switch between Windows Forms and WPF if a solution is only possible on one of them.

Comment: If you just need to load html pages why you need a hosting ? why can't you directly load the page into Webbrowser control by providing file paths ?

Comment: @AccessDenied because I will have to process posts as well.